# ie8 zebra table rows and hover

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I need a better way to do the following.  The performance after 10 rows just degrades into unusable.  at 100+, the browser just locks up.

this is an intranet ie8 enviro so it must work in ie8.

```
$('table.vgrid tr.xodd').hover(
    function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('xodd');
        $(this).addClass('rowhover');           
    } 
    , 
    function(){             
        if ($(this).attr("class")=='rowhover')
        {
            $(this).removeClass('rowhover');
            $(this).addClass('xodd');
        }
    }
);
$('table.vgrid tr.xeven').hover(
    function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('xeven');
        $(this).addClass('rowhover');           
    } 
    , 
    function(){ 
        if ($(this).attr("class")=='rowhover')
        {
            $(this).removeClass('rowhover');
            $(this).addClass('xeven');
        }
    }
);
```

html is as expected with vgrid class on the table and odd/even on alternating tr rows.

I've tried a few different ways and they all perform horribly.   More than just the zebra effect, I have other JS keying off it's current class so using the classes is borderline mandatory right now for fear of having to re-code half the site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's a good reason to remove the existing classes. If you set up your CSS so that styles for `.rowhover` are listed AFTER those for `.xeven` and `.xodd`, they will naturally override.

Then, all you'll need to do is [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) the `rowhover` class:

```
$('.vgrid tr').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rowhover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JJ2qJ/1/

---

But there's a pure-CSS approach that's even better: use the [`:hover`](http://caniuse.com/#search=hover) pseudoclass. Again, list those `:hover` styles AFTER the other `.xeven` and `.xodd` styles so they override.

(You may need to apply certain styles to the `tr:hover td` children instead of the `tr` itself. Try it and see what works best.)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JJ2qJ/

```
.vgrid .xeven {
    background-color: #999;
}
.vgrid .xodd {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.vgrid tr:hover {
    background-color: #9ff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I had previously tried this and found it didn't work as expected.  I forgot I had to force the X-UA header to make it go to standards mode even with the doc type.